# Add two Float values and get up to 2 precision values

Tags: python, decimal, precision

Can we get up to 2 precision values when we add 2 float values of containing 0 as 2nd precision without changing its **type as Float**

I have a snippet like

```
a = 1.20+1.20
print a
```

the output should be like

```
2.40
```

but I got the output as 2.4 because python rounds off

I've tried like this ,

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 3
Decimal(1.20)+Decimal(1.20)
Decimal('2.40')
```

But every time I need to change the precision value!

can we get as 2.40 without changing its type?
It should contain a float value as 2.40, not a string!

Comment: I need the value to be in float not in a string format! that is why I'm asking is it possible to get 1.20+1.20 =2.40 ???

Answer (score -1):

Yes! you can round a float number.

```
>>> round(2.675, 2)
2.67
```

You can see more details in [python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: OP's problem is formatting floating point numbers, not internal rounding.

Comment: you can use print('% 6.2f' % a), to print in the format

Comment: Sigh.  No.  OP wants to format `2.4` as `2.40`. Get it?  It's a formatting issue.  `round` won't help at all.